# How-to include if(isset inside a query

Tags: php, session, notice

This little piece of code gives Notice: Undefined index: placeno1

I know it can be fixed by using if(isset()), but I have no idea how to place this on the correct matter in this $query line.

Tried a lot, but can't get it right.

```
<?php 
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `place` WHERE `placeno` = '".$_SESSION['placeno'.$i]."' LIMIT 1");
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($query)){
?>
```

Solution is

```
<?php 
if(isset($_SESSION['placeno'.$i])) {
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `place` WHERE `placeno` = '".$_SESSION['placeno'.$i]."' LIMIT 1");
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($query)){
}
}
?>
```

Comment: But what would the query be if it's not set?

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: **Warning**: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Now it has been changed still vulnerable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Undefined index is a array notice. So possible notice source is `'placeno'.$i`. You need to check it on every loop.

I am assuming you are looping this code with `for()` loop. That is where `$i` is coming from.

```
<?php 
if (isset($_SESSION['placeno'.$i])) {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `place` WHERE `placeno` = '".$_SESSION['placeno'.$i]."' LIMIT 1");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($query)){
    }
}
?>
```

If it's a loop, you can stop the loop like this:

```
<?php 
if (!isset($_SESSION['placeno'.$i])) {
    break;
}
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `place` WHERE `placeno` = '".$_SESSION['placeno'.$i]."' LIMIT 1");
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($query)){
?>
```

Comment: Yes, the first option is the solution. Thnx!

Answer (score 0):

Use ternary operator:

```
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `place` 
      WHERE `placeno` = '".isset($_SESSION['placeno'.$i])?$_SESSION['placeno'.$i]:""."' 
      LIMIT 1");
  while($row = mysql_fetch_object($query)){
```

... and sanitizing and mysqli_ functions :P

Comment: Please read the question again. `$i` is not even defined, so, how is this going to work? Also, the OP seems to know about `isset()` -- I think the question was -- *how to fix the error*, rather than *how to hide it using isset()* :)

Comment: Well, if the execution reaches that point, and $i is not defined, there's nothing else we can do there, because _The whole program is WRONG_ . But to avoid the warning in the line, this is a valid option. Still, I think it has more sense with the isset($_SESSION['placeno'.$i]).

Comment: `$i` being set doesn't mean `$_SESSION['placeno'.$i]` is also set.

Comment: I leave it as it was, since it's the only way it has some sense to me.

Comment: if (isset($_SESSION['placeno'.$i])) { before the query is the solution

Comment: No. It's not. Read the title. It says "Inside a query". :)